# Bootstrap navbar: brand on left - login on right - collapsible menu on center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I want to create a navbar with 3 parts: brand logo on right, login buttons on left, and a centered collapsible menu:

desktop:

[image: navbar desktop]

mobile:

[image: navbar mobile]

**[Demo on bootply](http://www.bootply.com/EJbiRIXpOr)**

I have some problems with the current result:

1. can't align menu on center
2. I want the collapse button go to the other side of the page (against brand)
3. collapse button (expanded menu) is not working properly. (see the demo and image below)

this is the expanded menu:
[image]

it's a few days that I'm struggling with this. I have tried so many things. this is my most strait attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to  Sunil Gehlot, I solved it. The height problem was because of this:

```
.navbar {
  height: 60px;
}
```

I changed it to this:

```
.navbar {
  min-height: 60px;
}
```

and to position the login buttons I used absolute positioning:

```
.loginStatus{
   position: absolute;
   right:10px;
   top:10px;
}

@media (min-width: 200px){
  .loginStatus{
     right:100px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .loginStatus{
    right:10px;
  }
}
```

I wanted menu items to be centered in desktop and normally aligned in mobile:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .navbar-nav{
     text-align:center;
  }

  .navbar-nav {
      float: none !important;
      margin: 0;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
     float: none !important;
     display:inline-block !important;
  }
}
```

### [Full Demo](http://www.bootply.com/9pe6HuV2mW)

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps.

I have added `text-center` class on `ul` and i have used below `css`.

```
.navbar-nav {
    float: none !important;
    margin: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
.navbar-nav > li {
    float: none !important;
  display:inline-block !important;
}
}
```

please take a look [here](http://www.bootply.com/HyKYvvu8p9) and let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. it solves the first problem. what about the third?